# How can I simplify these mySQLi queries?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 5 similar queries which output a single number. The `payment_type` determines the output. Basically it will show how many transactions were done with Cash, Check, Credit, or Autopay for the year.

```
$getTxnX = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM transaction WHERE YEAR(paid_on) LIKE '%".date ('Y')."%'");
$getTxnC = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM transaction WHERE YEAR(paid_on) LIKE '%".date ('Y')."%' AND payment_type='C'");
$getTxnK = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM transaction WHERE YEAR(paid_on) LIKE '%".date ('Y')."%' AND payment_type='K'");
$getTxnO = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM transaction WHERE YEAR(paid_on) LIKE '%".date ('Y')."%' AND payment_type='O'");
$getTxnA = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM transaction WHERE YEAR(paid_on) LIKE '%".date ('Y')."%' AND payment_type='A'");
```

I am outputing the numbers using

```
if ( $row = $getTxnX->fetch_assoc() ) { 
    echo $row['num']; 
}
if ( $row = $getTxnC->fetch_assoc() ) { 
    echo $row['num']; 
}
if ( $row = $getTxnK->fetch_assoc() ) { 
    echo $row['num']; 
}
if ( $row = $getTxnO->fetch_assoc() ) { 
    echo $row['num']; 
}
if ( $row = $getTxnA->fetch_assoc() ) { 
    echo $row['num']; 
}
```

It works fine, but is there a way to simplify the queries into one, then use something like the following?:

```
if ( $row = $getNewTxnQueryHere->fetch_assoc() ) { 
    echo $row['X']; 
    echo $row['C']; 
    echo $row['K']; 
    echo $row['O']; 
    echo $row['A']; 
}
```

I plan to wrap `if ( $row = $getNewTxnQueryHere->fetch_assoc() ) { ... }` around my entire results area and use the `echo $row['X'];` in various places within.

Comment: GROUP BY payment_type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one query

```
$query = $con->query("SELECT payment_type, COUNT(*) as cnt AS num FROM transaction WHERE YEAR(paid_on) LIKE '%".date ('Y')."%' group by payment_type");
$data = array();
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $data[$row['payment_type']] = $row['cnt'];
}
```

all data will be in array `$data`, ex: `echo $data['C'];` or `echo $data['A'];` or for total `echo array_sum($data);`

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a single grouped query?

```
SELECT payment_type, count(*)
FROM transaction
WHERE payment_type IN ('X', 'C', 'K', 'O', 'A')
    AND YEAR(paid_on) = YEAR(curdate())
GROUP BY payment_Type
```

Comment: Thanks for this! So now I am using that along with `<?php if ( $row = $getTxn->fetch_assoc() ) { echo $getTxn['X']; } ?>` but i am getting "Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in..." in my error log.

Comment: your query probably failed and returned boolean false, which you then blindly used as an object. add some error handling. e.g. `$res = mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error($con));`-type stuff.